# Change duration of SKAction playSoundFileNamed

Tags: sprite-kit, skaction, playsound

How do i change the duration of a created sound created with `SKAction.playSoundFileNamed`:

`var sound = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("sound.mp3", waitForCompletion: false)`

I tried setting `sound.duration = 1.0` but with no luck so far ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, that is impossible with SKAction.playSoundFileNamed: method.

[duration](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKAction/duration) property specifies the time in seconds required for current action to complete.

When using [SKAction.playSoundFileNamed:](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKAction/playSoundFileNamed:waitForCompletion:) method you don't have control over the audio being played (no pausing, stoping, resuming pitching etc). It's meant to play a sound, nothing more.

Some useful links:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22590464/3402095

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21023417/3402095