# Use of an Audio Clip Causing Memory Leak

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, sprite-kit, skscene

I have a sprite-kit game scene (`SKScene`) that uses audio clips from time to time.  I don't want to create a new action (`SKAction`) every time I need to run a short audio clip since the sound could stutter.  So I initialize an action variable with a file name and get ready to use it when necessary.

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    let audioMatchAction = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("myAudio", waitForCompletion: false)
}
```

Then when I need to run this audio clip, I just use the following line of code.

```
self.run(audioMatchAction)
```

Considering all circumstances, there are some indications that the memory might be leaking when the view controller (`UIViewController`) sets a scene.  So I've used **Allocations** to see what's going on.  And it says that there are two leaks pointing to the `AudioToolbox` library.  Anyway, I've changed the line above to the following.

```
let waitAction = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 1.0)
self.run(audioMatchAction, withKey: "audio")
self.run(waitAction, completion: {
    self.removeAction(forKey: "audio")
})
```

Allocations still says that there are two leaks when the app transitions to the game view controller.  I've read a few dozen topics regarding `SKAction` and audio clips.  There are some topics where they suggest that we use `SKAudioNode` as opposed to `SKAction.playSoundFileNamed`.  I've tried that.  And the leaks remain.  I've even used `AVAudioPlayer`.  I still have two leaks.  If I stop calling audio clips altogether, Allocations won't report a leak, which tells me that use of these clips are causing the leaks.  So what can I do to stop audio clips from leaking memory?  Thanks.

**UPDATE**

I think I used the following lines of code for `AVAudioPlayer` yesterday to see if the leaks would disappear.

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    let audioURLMatch = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "myAudio", ofType: "caf")!) as NSURL
    var audioURLMatchPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        // audio //
        do {
            audioURLMatchPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: audioURLMatch as URL)
            audioURLMatchPlayer.prepareToPlay()
        } catch let error {

        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21022433/skaction-playsoundfilenamed-failed-at-500-mp3, where it is suggested that you use AVAudioPlayer instead. Okay, you say you've done that but it would be good if you'd show the code, since I use AVAudioPlayer and I assure you it doesn't leak if handled correctly.

Comment: @matt  Thanks for the comment.  I don't remember the exact code, but I do remember referring to the folllowing article.  https://dzone.com/articles/using-avfoundation-to-play-audio-in-an-skaction-in

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, declaring audioURLMatchPlayer as a type instead of instantiating the player will prevent the memory leak.

Use `var audioURLMatchPlayer: AVAudioPlayer?` instead of `var audioURLMatchPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()`